# Error'raise locationparseerror<url>.failed to parse'when installing packages in canopy

Tags: python, proxy, canopy

The code is :

```
pip install adict
```

I get the error `raise locationparseerror<url>.failed to parse:<ssfcc.pw>:<10029>`

then I configure the network in canopy according to https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469150-Using-Canopy-Behind-a-Proxy-Firewall

but when test these proxy specs ,raise error:
[image]
I restart canopy,run the code'pip install adict',get the error'no matching distribution found for adict'.
I tried a few other packages,raise the same error.
And I tried to reload canopy,it's no use.I'm using windows 7 and canopy 2.1.3.
I think there are some issues in my proxy settings,what should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: "I tried a few other packages,raise the same error." ... Please provide the full error message / traceback for the simplest of these.

Comment: Actually probably easiest if you file a support request from the Canopy Help menu ( Feedback Bugs). Please include the output from the Detailed Network Access Tests, and refer to this SO question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually,I install packages following the steps described in https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469690-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-User-Python-from-the-OS-command-line.

Comment: I have not enough reputations to ask questions with two or more links,so I did not provide more traceback details.

Comment: So sorry.I will try to file a support request about this problem.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I delete the environment variables about proxy in my computer.The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

For installation, pip connects to the network, and if you use a proxy server or firewall, you may need to set the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables in order to access some url from the command line.

Just set the following two environment variables in your system ( Linux/Windows)

HTTP_PROXY = http://username:password@proxyname:port

HTPS_PROXY = https://username:password@proxyname:port

and make sure there isn't any undesired extra characters in the values of the environment variable otherwise that is also one of the reasons for this 'parsing' error.